# sbit definitions with SDCC - Error: "initializer element is not constant"

Tags: c

I am facing this error when try to compile a C program using the SDCC compiler:

The part of programme that is causing error.

```
include(reg51.h)
define cmdport P3
define dataport P2
define q 100

(following  3 line are causing error.)
sbit at  cmdport^0  rs ;  //register select pin
sbit at  cmdport^1  rw ;  // read write pin
sbit at  cmdport^6  e ;  //enable pin
```

Comment: take the time to format your code, it is not easily readable right now.

Comment: That isn't valid C code. I'm not surprised that you get errors.

Comment: I have write a small part of code and if you are talking about # before define then i did it and if bout sbit declaration then in sdcc we define  <br>sbit rs = cmdport^0; as<br>sbit at  cmdport^0  rs ;

Comment: @Leon Heller: while this technically isn't ANSI C code, the original poster clearly stated he is using SDCC. The [__sbit __at language extension is clearly documented in the SDCC manual](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/doc/sdccman.html/node59.html#SECTION00441700000000000000).

Comment: would you mind if I edit your original question so that it's valid C? You have a good question here about sbit with SDCC, but it's being overshadowed by confusion around the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is not valid C. It should look like this:

```
#include <reg51.h>
#define cmdport P3
#define dataport P2
#define q 100
```

To create `sbit` definitions for the individual bits in `P3` (address 0xB0), you want:

```
__sbit __at (0xB0) rs; // P3.0
__sbit __at (0xB1) rw; // P3.1
__sbit __at (0xB6) e;  // P3.6
```

Though, if you look in `sdcc/includes/mcs51/8051.h` you'll find that there are already generic definitions for `P3_0` and so on, allowing you to write:

```
#define rs P3_0
#define rw P3_1
#define e  P3_6
```

I'd also recommend that you pick more descriptive names for your bit definitions than `rs`, `rw` and `e` as these may clash with variable names.

Comment: i was including like you but i could not add # in question.I also tried __ before sbit and at as they were warned by sdcc as depriciated.i just copy your code nd now my code is working fine.but still i can,t figure out the cause f problem.please let me to know.

Comment: @Zain Try the SDCC mailing list. That's a much better forum for detailed back and forth discussion

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is an assembly file - you need to run it through an assembler rather than the C compiler.

Many C compilers (especially gcc based ones) will recognise a file with a particular suffix (.s for example) and do the right thing for you - other compilers wont - if you're using a make file that was written for gcc with a different compiler you might find that it makes this mistake